# I tried making a quiz using tkinter in python and for some reason, i keep getting an error

Tags: python, tkinter

I had created a code to make a quiz in python. Everything works fine until we reach the end of the questions at which point we are given an error. I don't understand where it is going wrong?

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
global score
score = 0
root = Tk()
root.title('Quiz')
root.config(bg = 'black')

class Question:
    def __init__(self, question, correct_ans):
        self.question = question
        self.correct_ans = correct_ans

def checkResult(letter):
    global score
    if letter == correct_ans:
        score += 1
    getNewQuestion()

def getNewQuestion():
    currentQuestion = questions.pop()
    for i, var in enumerate((titleVar, aVar, bVar, cVar, dVar)):
        var.set(currentQuestion.question[i])

def buttons():
    question = Label(root, textvariable=titleVar)
    question.pack()

    A = Button(root, textvariable = aVar, command = lambda: checkResult('A'))
    A.pack()

    B = Button(root, textvariable = bVar, command = lambda: checkResult('B'))
    B.pack()

    C = Button(root, textvariable = cVar, command = lambda: checkResult('C'))
    C.pack()

    D = Button(root, textvariable = dVar, command = lambda: checkResult('D'))
    D.pack()

file_handle = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "easyquestion.csv") 
count = 0
score = 0

questions = []

with open('easyquestion.csv', 'r') as file_handle:
    # list_question = []
    displayQ = []
    for line in file_handle:
        line_sections = line.split(",")
        displayQ = line_sections[:-1]
        correct_ans = line_sections[-1]
        questions.append(Question(displayQ, correct_ans))

titleVar = StringVar()
aVar = StringVar()
bVar = StringVar()
cVar = StringVar()
dVar = StringVar()

currentQuestion = None
getNewQuestion()

canvas = Canvas(width = 100, height = 100, bg = 'black')
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "/Users/arjyo/Downloads/image.png")
canvas.create_image(10, 10, image = image, anchor = NW)

buttons()

root.mainloop()
```

You will need a csv file name "easyquestion.csv" that looks like this

```
what is the smallest country in the world?,a) Monaco,b) Vatican City,c)Luxembourg,d)Maldives,B
what is the largest country in the world?,a)Russia,b)USA,c)India,d)China,A
what is the largest continent in the world?,a)Europe,b)Africa,c)Asia,d)Australia,C
When did world war 2 start?,a)1945,b)1942,c)1918,d)1939,D
What did Isaac newton discover?,a)electricity,b)gravity,c)energy,d)magnetism,B
what is the scientific name for humans?,a)hetero sapians,b)homo sapiens,c)homo exodus,d)hetero exodus,B
what is the boiling pont of water?,a)110 degree C,b)373 degree C,c)100 deegre C,d)0 degree C,C
What is 2*3*4*5*0+7-4?,a)123,b)27,c)3,d)9,C
Who owns microsoft?,a)Google,b)apple,c)Microsoft,d) ubuntu,C
what is the denary value of: 01001111,a)64,b)70,c)15,d)79,D
```

this is the error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/arjyo/Documents/quiz experiments/Actual quiz trial.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    A = Button(root, textvariable = aVar, command = lambda: checkResult('A'))
  File "/Users/arjyo/Documents/quiz experiments/Actual quiz trial.py", line 20, in checkResult
    getNewQuestion()
  File "/Users/arjyo/Documents/quiz experiments/Actual quiz trial.py", line 23, in getNewQuestion
    currentQuestion = questions.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

any help is appreciated and if you see any problems or ways to improve the code, do let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh well... ```IndexError: pop from empty list```... Check if there is anything on your stack before popping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when it runs checkResult on the last question, it then calls getNewQuestion which tries to pop an empty list. I'm not familiar with tkinter but you need to have some kind of hook that checks questions isn't empty and then does something for the quiz being complete.

```
def checkResult(letter):
    global score
    if letter == correct_ans:
        score += 1
    if not len(questions) == 0:
        getNewQuestion()
    else:
        print("Quiz Complete")
        root.destroy() 
        #or call a function which deals with the quiz being over
```

Comment: this only works in printing the statement the quiz is complete. the program, aka the tkinter window, is still left running. Appreciate the attempt tho :)

Comment: that was a placeholder for what you wanted to do on finishing the quiz. Look here for closing the tkinter program. https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/66698/exit-a-tkinter-gui-program

I have added root.destroy() to my code above.

Comment: Also I have a slight issue, i am trying to get the score for the user at the end of the program but the score is showing only 0. I dont know what is happening

Comment: correct_ans is only defined once at the bottom so stays as "D" throughout. You need to make it a global beside score at the top.Then add this to getNewQuestion
`global correct_ans`

Answer (score 0):

try placing this code

```
questions = []

with open('easyquestion.csv', 'r') as file_handle:
    # list_question = []
    displayQ = []
    for line in file_handle:
        line_sections = line.split(",")
        displayQ = line_sections[:-1]
        correct_ans = line_sections[-1]
        questions.append(Question(displayQ, correct_ans))
```

after def

`def checkResult(letter):` because it's trying to pop empty list as questions = []

Comment: it still doesnt work and prints this error : 
  File "/Users/arjyo/Documents/quiz experiments/Actual quiz trial.py", line 48, in <lambda>
    C = Button(root, textvariable = cVar, command = lambda: checkResult('C'))
  File "/Users/arjyo/Documents/quiz experiments/Actual quiz trial.py", line 20, in checkResult
    getNewQuestion()
  File "/Users/arjyo/Documents/quiz experiments/Actual quiz trial.py", line 34, in getNewQuestion
    currentQuestion = questions.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list

Comment: do you have any other ideas?

Comment: priceless words, be wary of understanding how the code executes and what is trying to be achieved. Moving that code to after the function checkResult will have the same result as getNewQuestion doesn't run until a button is clicked by which point questions will have been created.